# Горизонтальная лента событий

Tags: html, css

Понадобился горизонтальный скроллируемый таймлайн, желательно на bootstrap. Что-то вроде фейсбуковской ленты, но "на боку". Каждый элемент ленты это блок фиксированного размера. Эскиз на картинке:

[image: лента]

Свои решения кажутся мне недостаточно элегантными. Хотелось бы "семантической" разметки без лишних элементов и inline стилей.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tTcfEzc.png (надеюсь, там все понятно, чередование можно сделать через nth-child). Есть еще вариант делать через `<dl>`, тогда номера годов будут в `<dt>`, а содержимое в `<dd>`. Как это для поисковика выглядит - не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо! Мысль понятна.

Comment: @Etki Пожалуйста, преобразуйте ваш комментарий в ответ.

Comment: Просто для тех, кто будет читать это. *li:nth-child(odd)* работает как ожидается, но *dt:nth-child(odd)* внезапно выполняется для каждого dt :) Для definition list надо использовать *dt:nth-of-type(odd)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный вариант, который мне приходит в голову - это сделать эту штуку списком. Само тело (центральная линия) - это `<ul>`, у которого задано фоновое изображение с повторением по вертикали, вложенные `<li>` располагаются горизонтально, но каждый второй с помощью псведоселектора `:nth-child` или дополнительного класса смещается вниз (с помощью `position: relative` или любым другим способом). Линии-отступы, указывающие на `<li>`, легко делаются с помощью псевдоселектора `:after` и `position: absolute`. Сам `<li>` внутри содержит два основных блока, первый из которых - это квадрат, второй - непосредственно год; для каждого второго `<li>` этот блок позиционируется абсолютно над основным блоком.

Главный вопрос, на который надо ответить - это должна ли эта штука быть адаптивной и перестраиваться в вертикаль. Потому что там сохранится структура, но процесс доведения этого всего до блеска съест все нервы. Аналогично - если линия предполагается пунктирной и должна быть выполнена пиксель-перфект.

Картинка-поясняшка

[image]

Comment: Да, эта штука должан быть адаптивной, я только не стал сразу усложнять вопрос.

Comment: по вашей наводке - неадаптвный вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/5u6180re/